# SSL error has occured

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios11

I uploaded my application on iTunes, It's also live but on some devices (Mostly iPhone7). I have got **SSL connection error** after upgrading Xcode or ios version to 11.4.
In iphone 6s or ipad is working fine but on client iphone 7 this error occur have attached screen shot  of error, I am not able to understand what going on, what need to changed.

**I have already added this code in info plist**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>yourdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

We also check server certificate they are also valid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**First Check your port for SSL and correct certificates used for SSL pinning**

Check code for SSL

```
 - (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
      return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
      if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
          [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

      [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
```